# error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds (Lambda java 8)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, bounds

I have a Tree object that contains children (HashMap) of Tree objects and so on.

I need to filter objects by numericPosition variable.

For example:

```
Tree mapTreeRoot = new Tree("Root",0);      
int answer = 111;

mapTreeRoot
    .addNode("ChilldOfRoot",111)
    .addNode("ChildOfRootExample1",222)
    .addNode("ChildOfRootExample1Example2",333);

Tree treeObj  = mapTreeRoot
        .children
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(map -> answer == map.getValue().numericPosition)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

In this case I should get a Tree object filtered by numericPosition 
 **Tree class**

```
   public Tree(String name,int numericPosition) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numericPosition = numericPosition;
    }

    public Tree addNode(String key,int numericPosition) {
        Object hasKey =  children.get(key);
        if(hasKey == null) {
             children.put(key,new Tree(key,numericPosition)); 
        }

        return children.get(key);
    }

    public Tree getNode(String key) {
         Object hasKey =  children.get(key);
         if(hasKey != null) {
            return children.get(key);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

**Just in case** 
I got this error: error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds

I have been following by this example but it's not working for me.
https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/

Also I have tried `HashMap<String,Tree> treeObj = mapTreeRoot`.. but got the same error message.

Comment: Your stream operation returns a map. This return value is incompatible to the treeObj which is no map.

Comment: @Calculator I tried to use HashMap<String,Tree> treeObj = mapTreeRoot... still the same issue.

Comment: What is the point of `("" + answer)` when `answer` is *already* a `String`?

Comment: `Collectors.toMap()` produces a map of type `Map` not `HashMap`.

Comment: @Andreas sorry, I have just an example.My work code is much bigger, you're right.I have just wrongly made an example.It was int.

Comment: @Calculator how to get a single object from Map? I need to a Tree object

Comment: @Oyeme `"111"` is not an `int`. Also, `numericPosition` is an `int` *(presumably)*, and `String.equals(int)` will never be true.

Comment: @Oyeme Are you truly asking us how to get an object of type `Tree`? You invoke `new Tree(...)` on an appropriate constructor.

Comment: @Andreas just updated to .filter(map -> answer == map.getValue().numericPosition);

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve], i.e. a full example.

Comment: @Andreas yes, I need get a Tree object filtered by numericPosition field.

Comment: @Oyeme Do you want to make a tree out of the filtered map or do you expect to get exactly one tree that fulfills the filter condition: map -> answer == map.getValue().numericPosition?

Comment: @assylias just added an example to generate an Tree of children.  mapTreeRoot
        .addNode("ChilldOfRoot",111)
        .addNode("ChildOfRootExample1",222)
        .addNode("ChildOfRootExample1Example2",333);

Comment: @Calculator correct, one tree that fulfils the filter condition.

Comment: you can use something like this. `Tree treeObj = mapTreeRoot.children
.values().stream().filter(map -> answer == map.numericPosition).findFirst().get();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter for exactly one tree you can use:

```
Tree treeObj = null;
Optional<Entry<String, Tree>> optional  = mapTreeRoot
        .children
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(map -> answer == map.getValue().numericPosition)
        .findAny();
if(optional.isPresent()){
    treeObj = optional.get().getValue();
}
```

Comment: I got this error: error: incompatible types: Entry<String,Tree> cannot be converted to Optional<Entry<String,Tree>>

Comment: @Oyeme Now it should work. The `get()` after `findAny()` was wrong in my answer.

Comment: Cheers. That's what I wanted!